# Images disappear when form is being submitted

Tags: css, forms, codeigniter, image

I have a contact page with a form and icons on the page with social media links and email address. When the form is submitted the icons/images disappear from the page however the form validates and is fine. I am using standard img tags and a class of floatLeft. I found a solution that worked for someone when they used position relative on their css but still no luck for me. It must be something to do with the css (at least i think it is). I have tried using codeigniters img snippet (I am using CI Framework) and the images are fine on form submit but not sure how to align a CI image tag with a P tag as they seem to drop under one another.

Any help or links to what may be the problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

RESOLVED:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/phone.png" alt="Phone" class="floatLeft"><p>123 456 789</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS and html (CI view) ?

Comment: I've just added the html and css that links to the problem and also the CI way ve tried (which works but note sure how to keep the icon and text on same line)- Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the style as the following:

```
img.floatLeft{
    float:left;
    left:-20px;
    position:relative;
}

.contact-info{
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    height:38px;
    font-size:14px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}
```

***Please make sure the image is downloaded since you use relative link in the image source.***

Comment: I used your css method and this still wouldn't work- until i read the last line in your comment. I am currently using my localhost so to fix this i used the method i have been using to load in my css and javascript. The code i used is above in my first post- Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put the `img`inside the `p`:

```
<p><?php echo img('assets/images/phone.png'); ?>Your paragraph here</p>
```

Then add some right padding to the image to have it offset from the text. Or am I missing something?